# cannot access org.hibernate.Session

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I added database functions to my e-commerce store project. I try to do it. When i change hibernate-core version on 4.0.1.Final server cant start up.
Debug under:
[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ENJk.png)
here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
       <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and here is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>praca</groupId>
    <artifactId>inz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and here is the error i got ->[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOYiD.png)
If you need more code I will add. I need help, I dont know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same problem. It was because of an incompatibility between Hibernate and Java. I see your Hibernate is 6.0.0.Final. If your Java is 1.8 or lower than that, then it will create a problem. For 6.0.0.Final Hibernate, you must have at least Java 11.

Here is the link:
https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/

Comment: I think you are right, but the link only seems to mention Hibernate 6.1 and 5.6, but not 6.0. Do you have the official compatibility info for 6.0?

Comment: No, sorry. But i have seen couple of Udemy Tutor saying hibenate 6.x, where x=>0 ist, to use only for above Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Hibernate is **6.1.5.Final** worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).